# Implicit conversion in array initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Why implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string` does not work in the latter case?
Link a reference to C++ standard if possible, please.

**Variant 1:**

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const char* a) {}
};

int main() {
   // works well for a "const char*" accepting constructor
   Foo* foo = new Foo[1] { "a" };
}
```

**Variant 2:**

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(std::string a) {}
};

int main() {
   // could not convert from "const char*" to "Foo"
   Foo* foo = new Foo[1] { "a" };
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an implicit cast. There is a cast (explicit type conversion) and type coalescing (implicit type conversion), decide which one.

Comment: check how's the page named:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Answer (score 6):

At most one user-defined conversion is allowed in a user-defined conversion sequence (12.3p4).

You can use an extra level of braces to make it work:

```
   Foo* foo = new Foo[1] { {"a"} };
```

Note that because of [a bug in clang](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15735) it requires `Foo` to have a default constructor `Foo::Foo()` even though it will not actually be called.

Comment: Hmm... Looks good, works well with g++, but not with clang([LWS example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4jHHSh$0))

Comment: @balki clang is broken; there's a simple workaround (add a default constructor).  Reporting the bug now.